# from park to addon domain damage my Wordpress Multisite. Please help I lost one child site

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I had primary domain (example1.com) in Usercode/public_html.
I had Wordpress multisite under parked domain (example2.com) in Usercode/public_html.
I had child sites under example2.com/mobile, example2.com/cp, and example3.com (parked domain of example1.com)

Then I did many changes:

1. Created subdomain main.example2.com and moved the WP multisite to the main subdomain in Usercode/public_html/main and created new database. At this point every thing in multisite worked fine.
2. I added domain example4.com and make it the primary domain. This is on folder Usercode/domains/example4.com/public_html.
3. I moved example2.com as addon domain, that make the domain to have its own folder Usercode/domains/example2.com/public_html.
4. I moved example3.com as addon domain, that make the domain to have its own folder Usercode/domains/example3.com/public_html.
5. Moved the data from Usercode/public_html/main to Usercode/domains/example2.com/public_html/main.

At this point I verified my WP multisite and the example2.com, example2.com/mobile, example2.com/cp work fine from wp-admin and site-pages, but example3.com did not work.

Another detail is that example2.com and example3.com as addon has ssl certificate. Attempting to fix WP problem I moved example3.com as parked to domain example2.com but still has WP problem and plus lost the ssl certificate.

I hope there is a way to edit some file to fix the path reference to the example3.com site.

Comment: I know I did many edits, the nomenclature of replacing domains to "example" domain naming is cumbersome to me and had to fix it many times to clarify the question. I am sorry if this made my question bad to answer.  I wont make anymore edits since I am sure now that is correct.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for my problem. Rename the child site from its domain to be a folder of the multisite domain.

Lost site: example3.com
Rename in WP network sites: example3.com -> example2.com/example3

This will make the child site and data reachable; from there you can export the site and its data. (Might be posible to recreate the child site in example3.com)